# EPPlus Shows System Argument Exception

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am having issue reading in some worksheet from a workbook using C# and EPPlus.

**Error Message**

```
name contains invalid characters
```

Even after multiple checks on the worksheet name, file name and column headers within the workbook to make sure there is no invalid characters, I am still facing the same error.

However, when I move the worksheet that i need from that same workbook to a new Excel file and save it with the same file name and worksheet name, I have no error while reading in.

Does anybody know how to solve or even encounter this problem?

**Code**

```
 using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(mStream))
 {
    //WorksheetId = 5
    var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[WorksheetId]; //This is the part that is causing error

      for (int i = 1; i <= ws.Dimension.End.Column; i++)
      {
         dt2.Columns.Add((i - 1).ToString());
      }
 }
```

Comment: What's the value of `WorksheetId`?

Comment: 5, worksheetId is actually the sheet id in the workbook.

Comment: Your excel file contains 5+ Sheets? And what is the name of that sheet?

Comment: My excel file contains 11 Sheets. the sheetname is inputs. Other sheet name only contain alphabet characters.

Comment: Have you tried after renaming the sheet name.

Comment: There was a [bug](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/362) in Epplus, fixed in newer version.

Comment: Yeap, i tried renaming the sheet name but still have the same issues. The Epplus im using is the latest version, 4.5.3.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192719/discussion-between-muhammad-hannan-and-lel).

Comment: I tried for a little while and could not produce the error. I suppose something must be corrupt in the original file or it is an unknown bug in EPPlus. The developers should be happy if you could build a mock file which produces the error and submit it to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came across this [LINK](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/449) and realized this is actually a bug in EPPlus for version 4.5.2.2 onward.

After reverting back to the older version, everything works fine.

Comment: This is true. I've run into this now. Thanks!

Comment: Downgraded from 4.5.3.1 to 4.5.2.1 and the problem went away.  Note that version 5 changes to a commercial model, and the last free version 4.5.3.3 still has the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a change the "name" as mentioned in the error is not the sheet name.. There is a section in the Formular tab of the Excel software called "Name Manager".
There you will find list of names and references there. The error above per the source code of EPPlus is generated when EPPlus tries to validate the name range.
I had to modify the EPPlus source code to ignore the error since the file i was dealing with was locked and needed to be preserved as it was.